# How can you stop a user from entering an incorrectly formatted date on the fly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In a perfect world I would be able to stop the user from entering a character in a textbox on a asp.net page if it was not the next expected character in the specified date format.

For the format: dd-mm-yyyy if a user were to type "22" followed by anything but the "-" nothing would happen.

Is there a way this is possible using javascript, I have validation currently that checks the dates for the correct format, but this only occurs on a button click.

In this scenario all users will know the correct format, and should only ever be caught out when making a mistake, which this method should quickly (instantly) rectify.

Comment: This is called "input masking". Have a search on that term, or look here: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/javascript-input-masks/ maybe something like that is what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ready to use jquery then you can use
date mask plugin
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DateMask

Answer (score 2):

Add an [`onInput`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput) event handler, perform there the validation against the pattern, and rectify `<input>`'s value as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ is a descent masking plugin. If you are not using jQuery, you should start :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it can happen. Given a date format you can compare what the user entered via the KeyUp/KeyPress event of the text box in java script.

Using JQuery this can be implemented rather simply:

```
$(function(){

    $('#mytextbox').bind('keypress', function(event){

        //this assumes that the format is dd-mm-yyyy        

        //the text in the textbox
        var text = $('#mytextbox').val();

        //last character entered
        var lastCharIndex = (text.length-1) < 0 ? 0 : (text.length -1);
        var lastChar = text[lastCharIndex];

        if( lastCharIndex == 0 ){            //corresponds to the first d in dd

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 1 ) {    //corresponds to the second d in dd

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 2 ) {    //corresponds to the first '-' in dd-mm-yyyy

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 3 ) {    //corresponds to the first m

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 4 ) {    //corresponds to the second m

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 5 ) {    //corresponds to the second '-'

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 6 ) {    //corresponds to the first y

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 7 ) {    //corresponds to the second y

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 8 ) {    //corresponds to the third y

        } else if (lastCharIndex == 9 ) {    //corresponds to the forth y

        } else {                             //default error handling

        }

    });

});
```

So in each if statement all you have to check is if the `e.keyCode` (or the equivalent in the specified browser) is numeric or '-'. The reason I rather use the `lastChar` is so that I don't have to mess around figuring out what browser this is supposed to support...

Anyways if the `lastChar` is neither just set the textbox's text to be the text it already had minus the last character entered, unless of course the text entered only had 1 character in which case the text box's contents should be set to blank `''`.

Bleepzter

Answer (score 0):

A possibly cheap way I found is to use the `OnKeyUp` event ([source](http://benreichelt.net/blog/2006/03/02/firing-javascript-events-when-textbox-changes/)), which will fire after every keystroke.

Comment: It's [recommendable](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript) to use [`oninput`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput) instead.